# Making another Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $results and I did a print_r of that array and got this...

```
Array ( [0] => 
            Array ( [invoiceid] => 992 [client] => www [invoicedeliverymethod] => email [date] => 2011-11-04 [enddate] => 2011-10-31 23:59:59 [total] => 103.00 [remainingbalance] => 0.00 [ispaid] => Yes [isagentpaid] => No [datedistributed] => 2011-11-04 [invoicedcontact] => 1 ) 
        [1] => 
            Array ( [invoiceid] => 991 [client] => www [invoicedeliverymethod] => email [date] => 2011-11-04 [enddate] => 2011-09-30 23:59:59 [total] => 103.00 [remainingbalance] => 0.00 [ispaid] => Yes [isagentpaid] => No [datedistributed] => Not distributed [invoicedcontact] => 1 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [invoiceid] => 988 [client] => Sylvester Services [invoicedeliverymethod] => email [date] => 2011-11-04 [enddate] => 2011-10-31 23:59:59 [total] => 16687.83 [remainingbalance] => -14527.00 [ispaid] => No [isagentpaid] => No [datedistributed] => Not distributed [invoicedcontact] => 1 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [invoiceid] => 987 [client] => Colony Holland Lumber [invoicedeliverymethod] => email [date] => 2011-11-04 [enddate] => 2011-10-31 23:59:59 [total] => 8345.39 [remainingbalance] => -8245.39 [ispaid] => No [isagentpaid] => No [datedistributed] => Not distributed [invoicedcontact] => 1 ) 
)
```

What I am trying to do is make an array of just the [invoiceid] I am very new to PHP and any help information would be awesome! Thanks

Comment: User please try and accept some of your answers.

Comment: Why? All you're doing is duplicating information you've already got.

Answer (score 1):

```
$invoicedIds = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $invoicedIds[] = $result['invoiceid'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's easy...

```
$invoice_array = null;

foreach ($original_complex_array as $id => $elements){
$invoice_array[$id] = $elements['invoiceid'];
}
```

So you know to which element id (whatever it is) match that invoiceid.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($results as $r){
  $new_array[] = $r['invoiced'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$invoiceIDArray=array();
foreach ($bigArray as $subArray)
{
    $invoiceIDArray[]=$subArray['invoiceid'];
}

echo print_r($invoiceIDArray,true)."\n";
?>
```

The above goes through the all emcompassing array to get access to the sub-arrays. Then, it just puts each `invoiceid` into another array

Answer (score 0):

If invoiceid is always the first element in each sub-array, you can do:

```
$invoice_ids = array_map('current',$array);
```